# Store a matrix in Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following matrix:

```
        item_1  item_2  item_3
item_1       1       0       0
item_2       0       2       0
item_3       0       0       3
```

What is the best way to store this matrix into django, so that in the future I can retrieve an entire column (being able to see the ID of each row), and use it to perform some calculations in a view?

Obs: This matrix is going to have thousands of columns and rows.

Comment: can you use a SQL database? if you're looking for a lightweight one just for storing and retrieving purposes, sqlite is a good option. you can also store your matrix in a pickle `.pkl` or numpy file `.npy` and retrieve it later

Comment: @Alireza If I use a pickle file wouldn't I have to load the entire data each time that I need to retrieve it? Wouldn't this have performance issues?

Comment: I'm not sure about Django pipeline and loading procedures. maybe you can specify somehow to keep the variable in the cache. look it up please. as in case of flask, I'm quite sure that you load it only once per each thread.

Answer (score 1):

Probably best to make an Cell model, with 3 fields; column, row, value.

```
class Cell(models.Model):
    col = models.CharField(max_length=50, index=True)
    row = models.CharField(max_length=50, index=True)
    value = models.IntegerField()
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('col', 'row')
```

With this, you can do easy calculations.

```
col_sum = Cell.objects.filter(col='Abc').aggregate(sum=Sum('value'))['sum']
row_sum = Cell.objects.filter(row='Zyx').aggregate(sum=Sum('value'))['sum']
```

Comment: Could you please explain what the meta class does? And is there a way that I can upload my current data to this database?

Comment: Meta gives your Model a bit more metadata, which Django can use to build your tables properly. Here I use it to make sure the combinations of a row and column is unique. For some more info, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#meta-options.

Comment: About upload, if you choose a database system, Django will make sure the data is properly stored. To migrate your data into the database requires some scripting, but is possible.